Collision Update on a Manipulator Links
I am trying to apply a pick-and-place operation with the Fanuc 6 DOF robot. I am using Moveit2 to give motion planning commands to robot. It sometimes gets into limit error during the execution of planned path. Because robot axises (links) are very close to each other in some particular robot position such as the following image:


When I checked the explanation of the error from manual, it says:

Most robots have interaction limits, in addition to normal joint
limits. Even when all axes are within their respective limits an error
might occur. This could possibly be caused by the interaction between
multiple axes.

This situation occurs when other links are so close to link_1 (blue arrow on image)

My Solution Trials

Increasing the volume of link_1 to prevent Moveit to plan a risky
situation for robot. I tried to scale up the link_1 SDF file via online
tools but then I couldn't attached it to the robot.
Attachment of an external link such as sphere on top of link_1 on URDF
to be sure that other links can't get close to it. However I faced
with path planning failure on Moveit(SRDF is also updated).


Do you have any suggestions about this issue?
Thank you for your time.

I added an external box link and attached it to link_1. However, this time I paid attention to not sizing the box which collides with neighbor links. In addition, I updated the self-collision matrices on the SRDF file by using Moveit_Setup_Assistant.

